# Spring @Autowired not working in some classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

So i am using Spring to access my DB and fetch Users based on different Properties. With a @Restcontroller I get the Data. I created a UserRepository which extends the CrudRepository.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
Iterable<User> findByNachname(String nachname);

    Iterable<User> findByRolle(Rolle rolle);

    Optional<User> findByBenutzername(String benutzername);

    @Transactional
    String deleteByBenutzername(String benutzername);
}
```

I use @Autowire to get an Instance of the UserRepo in my Controller-class

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

This works perfectly fine in all Controllers i have.
But now when i try the same in another class the userRepository Instance is null.

```
public class Authentificator {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

The Authentificator and the LoginController are not in the same package. But both of them are not in the same package as the UserRepo.

- project

  - UserRepo-package
  - Controller-Package
  - Authentificator-Package

Comment: It seems Authentificator is not a Spring bean. Is it? How do you get an instance of it? Spring only autowires dependencies in Spring beans, which must be created by Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must make sure *Authentificator* is also a spring bean - I mean you must annotate it with something like @Component or @Service. After this step you’ll also have to “get” the *Authentificator* instance from spring instead of instantiating it with the *new* keyword.

Comment: After getting rid of getting the `Authentificator` through instantiating it with _new_ it now works perfectly fine

Comment: oh, then that’s it :)

Answer (score 3):

`@Autowired` does work only with the spring context. This means that it will work only with class instances which are managed by Spring. Your `Authentificator` class is managed by you and Spring does not have to take care or know about it, it's not important for the Java Framework.

This is more of a configuration issue rather than an annotation issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Spring to inject a field in `Authenticator` object the dependent object must be also created by Spring. You can do it by marking this class as a `@Component` or by creating a method with `Authenticator` return type marked with `@Bean`annotation. Then it must be injected somewhere.